# How do I toggle sub menu items on a navigation?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I am working on an accessible navigation and would like to toggle submenu items on click using the same click handler but their closest respective sub-menu-items. (Any accessibility help is a bonus.) Is the only way to do this by setting an ID? If so, I would like this to be dynamic in the JS where the data-id is not hardcoded.

```js
function handleSubmenuToggle() {
  console.log('click');
  document.querySelector('.sub-menu-items').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.nav-menu-container {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  padding: 1.3125rem 1.875rem;
}

.menu-item {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

.sub-menu-items {
  background: white;
  display: none;
  left: -25px;
  min-width: 183px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}

.sub-menu-items.show {
  display: block !important;
}

.sub-menu-items:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid white;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 42%;
}

.sub-menu-items a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu-items a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav aria-label="Empower Reservation Navigation" class="nav-menu-container">
    <ul class="menu-items">
      <li class="menu-item slds-is-relative">
        <button aria-label='Toggle Button' aria-pressed='pressed' onclick="handleSubmenuToggle();">Menu Item 1 <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
        <ul class="sub-menu-items">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item slds-is-relative">
        <button aria-label='Toggle Button' aria-pressed='pressed' onclick="handleSubmenuToggle()">Menu Item 2<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
        <ul class="sub-menu-items">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item slds-is-relative">
        <button aria-label='Toggle Button' aria-pressed='pressed'>Tools <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
        <ul class="sub-menu-items">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item slds-is-relative">
        <button aria-label='Toggle Button' aria-pressed='pressed'>Contact [Name] <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
        <ul class="sub-menu-items">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Thanks in advance!

https://codepen.io/fawn-marie/pen/GRBobNX?editors=1111

Comment: Suggest you remove the commented out HTML

Answer (score 1):

W3 has some great examples how to implement WCAG features with ARIA attributes. A specific example could be found here: [Navigation Menubar Example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/menubar/menubar-navigation).

Give the `<button>` element two new aria attributes

1. `aria-haspopup` to indicate that there is a flyout submenu;
2. `aria-expanded` to provide information if the flyout is visible or not

By doing this you're giving the `<button>` the control over the state of the submenu. `aria-expanded` will now tell you the current state of the submenu. You can manipulate this state through JavaScript by setting the attribute value with [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Then you can open and close your submenu by styling the submenu based on the `aria-expanded` value. Since the button is a sibling of the submenu, you can use the sibling selector `+` to select the submenu whenever the button has a certain attribute, like this.

```css
ul.submenu {
  display: none;
}

button[aria-expanded="true"] + ul.submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

The cool thing about this is that the `<button>` is the **only** authority over the submenu. From here you only have to listen for clicks on the button to toggle the `aria-expanded` state. The rest will be governed by CSS.

I suggest you look at the W3 link as it shows more attributes that you should use in this kind of structure to improve accessibility.

```js
const subMenuToggles = document.querySelectorAll('.sub-menu-toggle');

document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const subMenuToggle = event.target.closest('.sub-menu-toggle');
  if (subMenuToggle === null) {
    return;
  }
  
  for (const toggle of subMenuToggles) {
    if (toggle.hasAttribute('aria-haspopup')) {
      toggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
    }
  }
  
  if (!subMenuToggle.hasAttribute('aria-haspopup')) {
    return;
  }
  
  if (subMenuToggle.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true') {
    subMenuToggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
  } else {
    subMenuToggle.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
  }
});
```

```css
.nav-menu-container {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  padding: 1.3125rem 1.875rem;
}

.menu-item {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 0.75rem;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-item button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

.sub-menu-items {
  display: none;
  background: white;
  left: -25px;
  min-width: 183px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}

.sub-menu-toggle[aria-expanded="true"] + .sub-menu-items {
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu-items:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid white;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 42%;
}

.sub-menu-items a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu-items a:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav aria-label="Empower Reservation Navigation" class="nav-menu-container">
    <ul class="menu-items">
      <li class="menu-item slds-is-relative">
        <button class="sub-menu-toggle" aria-label='Toggle Button' aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu Item 1 <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></button>

        <ul class="sub-menu-items">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="menu-item slds-is-relative">
        <button class="sub-menu-toggle" aria-label='Toggle Button' aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu Item 2<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></button>

        <ul class="sub-menu-items">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="menu-item slds-is-relative">
        <button class="sub-menu-toggle" aria-label='Toggle Button' aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Tools <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
        
        <ul class="sub-menu-items">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="menu-item slds-is-relative">
        <button aria-label='Toggle Button' aria-pressed='pressed'>Contact [Name] <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
        
        <ul class="sub-menu-items">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Sub Menu Item 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: When you start to do things like aria-haspopup="true", role="menu", role="menuitem" etc. keep in mind: ARIA menus are not designated for navigation but for application behavior which is an entirely different thing perhaps.  re: the aria-haspopup="true"  are activated on click which is not really a menu but only to reveal the hidden menu.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your statement? I'm curious to know if my example is correct in this context. Finding real-world examples for accessibility are hard to come by, so I kept the aforementioned W3 example as reference.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss is correct even though the W3 example you posted is for navigation. When you use the `menu` role and the associated ARIA attributes, you are making a commitment to implement the up/down/left/right arrow keys for navigation. If you try the W3 example, you'll see you can't TAB through the menu - you have to arrow through it. I find it simpler to use simple lists of links and `aria-expanded` on the main menu. Look at the [Disclosure Navigation Menu pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/disclosure/disclosure-navigation.html) instead.

Comment: Not saying your answer is "wrong" and yes real world examples are hard to find I would agree.  Keep in mind the navigation by keyboard, click, touch, tab etc. and tab order is important.   Note that you cannot assume size either since some large screens (think of the museum you visit which likely has these large touch devices nowadays) are touch as are newer laptops.  ARIA is mainly for JAWS screen reader (no harm in including it).  Top level link should behave like a link not a button for example.

Comment: Thank you all! @EmielZuurbier Do you know if there is a way to close any open ones if the other pop-up is already open?

Comment: Thank you for insights. This helps a lot in my own understanding and application of assistive technologies.

Comment: @Fawn I've modified the answer to close all submenus before opening a new one.